# Começar uma activity a partir de um item no bottom navigation (barra de menu)

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Tenho a *activity main* e um *bottom bar navigation* com 4 itens. Quando inicio a aplicação, ela começa, mostra a *activity* do primeiro item. Eu queria fazer com que ela "começasse" a partir do item 3. É possível fazer isso? Como?

Comment: Utilize o método [**setSelectedItemId**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setSelectedItemId(int))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaração:

```
AHBottomNavigationViewPager viewPagerBottom;
AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigation;
```

Para iniciar no fragment escolhido faça isso no OnCreate ou onde ele já identificou os itens:

```
viewPagerBottom.setCurrentItem(posição);
```

Para acompanhar a seleção do botão correspondente vc faz:

```
bottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(posição);
```

Comment: É isso mesmo, muito bem, valeeu !